# Is this intuition correct? (dot product)

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, speed

So, it is based on the article below: Go to the bottom of the article where the 'Mario-Kart Speed Boost' example is.

So, the intuition in the examples makes sense to me but sometimes people explain things clearly but incorrectly. Maybe this is one such case.

https://betterexplained.com/articles/vector-calculus-understanding-the-dot-product/

Some Q's:
a. Is the dot product in this case telling us simply about the amount of boost that will be assigned?
b. is it telling us anything about speed?

Comment: In the article I believe the "boost" is actually treated as a fixed velocity. The total speed *added* to your kart speed will be that "Total" value. So (a) yes, (b) a little bit, the speed of the kart before hitting the "boost pad" could be anything, and the speed afterwards depends on the speed before and the angle of interaction. (|a||b|cos(theta))

Comment: Please make this question "self containing". All the necessary information to answer your question should be written here.